# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to run the first program of appium. But getting the below mentioned error. I have downloaded the latest selenium 4 jars and java.client (appium jars.). Still it says noClassFoundException.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Answer (score 6):

Appium refers to a class in Selenium that was moved to a diffirent package in Selenium 4.
I get this compatibility table from [appium conversation](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1273#issuecomment-559773917) on github:

| Appium | Selenium |
| --- | --- |
| 8.0.0-beta | 4.1.0 |
| 7.3.0 | 3.141.59 |
| 7.2.0 | 3.141.59 |
| 7.1.0 | 4.0.0-alpha-1 |
| 7.0.0 | 3.141.59 |