# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running Appium using Java

Tags: java, appium

Trying to automate native app on android device using Appium (Java) and faced this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
at wibu.main(wibu.java:21)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 1 more

Here's my code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class wibu {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        dc.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.facebook.katana");
        dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),dc);

        String facebook_username = "username";
        String facebook_password = "password";

        MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByAccessibilityId("Username");
        el1.sendKeys(facebook_username);
        MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByAccessibilityId("Password");
        el2.sendKeys(facebook_password);
        MobileElement el3 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByAccessibilityId("Log In");
        el3.click();
        MobileElement el4 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.Button[1]");
        el4.click();
        MobileElement el5 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementById("com.google.android.gms:id/credential_save_reject");
        el5.click();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your appium java-client version? Do you have also selenium dependency?

Take a lool at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742325/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-remote-internal-jsontowebele

Comment: I'm using java-client 7.6.0 and looking at your given page, I'm supposed to use 8.0.0 java-client since I'm using Selenium 4.1.0?

Comment: Yes, java client 8 should be used with selenium 4. 7.6.0 is incompatible.

Comment: I tried to run it with java-client 8.0.0 included, but another error was found. I can't import the MobileElement class

Comment: and what do you mean by "selenium dependency"?

Comment: Dependncy means the library in the project classpath. Appium 8 has some changes, https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md

Comment: Changed my code based on new updates and also replaced the java client version, but new error occurs. "java: type io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver does not take parameters"

Comment: AndroidDriver<WebElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),dc);

Did I code it correctly?

Comment: this `<WebElement>` should be removed from AndroidDriver. 

Feel free to look at this api documentation regarding available methods and arguments: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.appium/java-client/latest/index.html

Comment: You saved me haha, the program is running rn. Thanks for the assist

Comment: The code was running without having a problem, but when I try to run the code again, it gives me an error, it says "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."

Comment: I'm pretty sure the elements were located correctly

Comment: You have to share the code again. And the result of `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` command too. And the line number, which throws an exception. So it will be possible to figure out what happened.

Comment: Just figured out the problem, thanks again :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually,

the original issue was that *java-client 7.6.0* is not compatible with Selenium 4.

In order to use Selenium 4, appium version should be 8+.

The latest appium-java client version is `8.0.0-beta2`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/8.0.0-beta2

**Migration from Appium 7 to 8**

The list of breaking changes listed in this guide:

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md

- `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>` should be `AndroidDriver`
- `MobileElement` should be `WebElement`
- `findElementByAccessibilityId` should be `findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("..."))`, etc.

And for double-check, the recent API docs available here:

https://javadoc.io/doc/io.appium/java-client/latest/index.html