# Appium driver list command is not working on windows

Tags: appium, appium-android

If I type *appium* in the command line.It runs successfully

*appium driver list* doesn't list available drivers that I can add to my project.

Error message:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js: error: unrecognized arguments: driver list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to update your Appium "npm install appium@next -g" but as of now it will download the beta version.
- Then run the "appium driver list"

[image]

if you encountered error using the beta version please check this link for your reference.

[additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120744/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-appium-us)